Django Quill-Editor в сочетании django-modeltranslation. Не удаётся отобразить текст, когда выбран другой язык
У меня возникла следующая ситуация с использованием Django Quill-Editor и django-modeltranslation.
По умолчанию modeltranslation использует резервные языки, в случае если нет перевода на текущий выбранный язык. Но с полями QuillField это не работает.
У меня в модели есть title (charField) и text (QuillField). Поле title он отображает, а там где должен быть text пусто. Скорее всего причина в том, что django-modeltranslation, не поддерживает такие поля для обработки по умолчанию.
Есть ли способ как-то их подружить, чтобы text начал тоже отображаться?
